# Uploaded video process by python code on server

Tags: python, video, uploading

I have a python code on a server and if I upload a video from mobile to the server,so How can I provide path of that video to the python code if I want every video should prodceed by the python code

Comment: Please provide a sample code that people can see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I can't provide that cade as my team does not allow me to show code to anyone.

Comment: You can just tell me the way to archive that .

Comment: Just imagine that I have a video editing python program on the server and when I upload video from my device , Now both program and video are on server I just want to know how can I make connection between python program and video on the server .that video should be proceed by python program .And that's all done on the server.

Comment: still need more explanation, what kind of interaction do you mean ? Like passing parameter to the python code ? the file content itself to python ? running the python code when the file uploaded? Which kind of input Does your python code accept ? As I said, we have to know those details in order to help.

Comment: Ok, just suppose that I have a python program that is capable to edit video , now I upload a video from my phone but as you know Android phone does not provide suitable environment for python that's way I have to put that video editable python code on server now I upload video from mobile to server   now I have both things on server 1. Python code is on server and video which I upload from moblie is also on the server I just want to know that  how should I provide path of that video to the python code that I store both python code and video in different folders

Comment: Take server as priority.dont think about the python code or how I upload video from mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I have doubts that your explanation has truly reflects what you need. First of all servers accept every thing "as it is" as long as the input has the appropriate format for that specific "server". In your case, the video might be a stream, binary, or event encoded data in to a "socket" in your "server". the framework should not matter. So when you have a stream you should be able get it in to your "server" to be processed. If you have problem in that sense, you should try to look first how "servers" accept input. I assume you're knowledgable for that. Let's say you have a nginx server on a linux machine which also has a python included. So your web server should be configured to run in python (Django or something similar). Once you started to upload your file, the content can be passed as async, or sync process in python (I think I should not mention how RESTFull model work on http). When you have the data (stream or static/bulk), you should be able to whatever you want to do with that data.